# jQuery toggle() not always firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been making some basic mobile navigation and am using a click event to show/hide the menu.

A reduced code sample:

```
        jQuery('.menu-button').click(function(){
            jQuery('.header-nav').toggle();
            console.log('clicked');
        });
```

I've been remotely debugging on mobile and the console.log always works, but the `.header-nav` `toggle()` seems to randomly not trigger - I can't spot a pattern to it, but it always remains in the DOM (which it should), so it being somehow removed is not the reason why it is not firing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remains in the DOM how exactly, `toggle` doesn't remove anything, it just hides it ?

Comment: Sorry - I mean it's staying in the DOM (which it should), so it being somehow removed is not the reason why it is not firing.

Comment: Use ontouch event rather than click event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android

Comment: Most likely the click event is sometimes being triggered twice, or something else is toggling the element.

Comment: Kevin B - that does seem to be the case actually - counting the console.log's - any idea why that happens?

Comment: are you facing this issue only in mobile devices or in desktop browsers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin B's comment it seems that the click event is firing multiple times. To fix this, the following was used:

```
$(element).off().on('click', function() {
    // function body
});
```

Reference: [jQuery click events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

Comment: or... you could move the click event from inside whatever event handler it is in to somewhere else. clearly you don't need to re-bind it.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily I good solution.  Ideally you would find the root cause of "extra" clicks.  Good luck! :)

Comment: It's one of those 'works for now' fixes - going to try and investigate further. It's strange though as it's quite a simply function that is called in document.ready and window.resize.

Comment: You need to handle 300ms delay when onclick is fired on mobile devices (mostly happen in android smartphones).

Comment: I think that could be the culprit as the same problem doesn't exist on mobile. Fastclick.js seems to be the easiest way to solve this but it seems like a lot of code to remove this Android 'feature'.

Comment: you can tackle it by detecting user agent easily for android.